# Javascript : Is it possible to animate the fillRect of a shape in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I want to animate the filling of a shape by making the fill grow from the center until it covers the entire shape. I am using squares. Currently I have this which gives it a solid fill without animation:

```
this.ctxGrid.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
```

I want to animate it however. Is it possible? If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but not automatically. Increment the `dx` over time using `requestAnimationFrame`.  There is not flag or function that will automatically add animations.

Comment: Im sorry, but I am kind of a beginner, not quite, but could you give me an example of using requestAnimationFrame? I don't know how it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to do this automatically.  You need to do it yourself by adjusting the `dx`/`dy` of the `fillRect` over time.  You can do this in a call to `requestAnimationFrame`.  See quick example below.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let x = canvas.width * 0.5;
let y = canvas.height * 0.5;
let dx = 0;
let dy = 0;

ctx.fillStyle = "green";

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, dx, dy);
  x -= 1;
  y -= 1;
  dx += 2;
  dy += 2;
  if (x <= 0) return;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to fill just like that, but from the center outwards?